# Spigot - ApplicationManager quit unexpetedly

Tags: crash

Since a few days ago, about every 20 seconds a popup window appears saying that ApplicationManager quit unexpectedly:
[image]

I can't think what I could've done to cause this, but what is ApplicationManager and how can I fix this?

Here are the details:

```
Process:               ApplicationManager [606]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/Spigot/ApplicationManager
Identifier:            ApplicationManager
Version:               1.1 (1.1.18)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           ApplicationManager [606]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-07-29 12:47:08.680 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        E4B4645B-EC16-FB4D-45E7-8FFBF15AF282


Time Awake Since Boot: 450 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** CFRelease() called with NULL ***

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9341c010 CFRelease + 912
1   ApplicationManager              0x0000000100011bfd main + 2407
2   ApplicationManager              0x0000000100001704 start + 52

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96031232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff945dea6a  _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9603094a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff99af140d start_wqthread +    13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff9376f7ba  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00000000000fc080  rdx: 0x00000000000e7200
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00000001000a4400  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbffbf0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbffbb0
   r8: 0x0000000000000029   r9: 0x0000000100300000  r10: 0x000000000000002a  r11: 0x0000000100300000
  r12: 0x000000010001349c  r13: 0x0000000100300410  r14:  0x0000000100304360  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff9341c010  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00000001002e7000

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100070ff7 +ApplicationManager (1.1 - 1.1.18) <5913B635-712D-3139-9D9B-62A5EBF01BA5>      /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/Spigot/ApplicationManager
    0x7fff6304a000 -     0x7fff63080837  dyld (353.2.1) <72A99D0F-0B56-3938-ABC5-67A0F33757C4> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8add9000 -     0x7fff8afe6ffb  com.apple.CFNetwork (720.4.4 - 720.4.4) <71A596B3-A837-3ADF-9560-1DCDA9292F96>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff8afe7000 -     0x7fff8b002ff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (34)   <D64842BE-7BD4-3D0C-9842-1D202F7C2A51> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff8b003000 -     0x7fff8b01cff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.10 - 187) <2BF2705E-2CC6-37E7-BD49-D4B4E01591E3>     /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CF  OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff8b01d000 -     0x7fff8b01effb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8b10d000 -     0x7fff8b111fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib (79.1) <201EF6DF-5074-3CB7-A361-398CF957A264>    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMC  lient.dylib
    0x7fff8b112000 -     0x7fff8b11bff3  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0) <07FD1753-5498-310F-8C58-49E2F27C614B>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAut h
    0x7fff8b11c000 -     0x7fff8b13dfff  com.apple.framework.Apple80211   (10.3 - 1030.71.6) <C0A17391-5C8B-34B1-BD46-8D644AB57DE0>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Apple80211
    0x7fff8b13e000 -     0x7fff8b169ff3  libarchive.2.dylib (30)  <8CBB4416-EBE9-3574-8ADC-44655D245F39> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
    0x7fff8b27b000 -     0x7fff8b27cff3  libSystem.B.dylib (1213) <AD223AEB-237D-35A3-825E-EECF95916838> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8b27d000 -     0x7fff8b280fff    com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <D94F7F86-4015-3453-92FD- ADC04F215C04>  /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceMa nagement
    0x7fff8b281000 -     0x7fff8b398fe7  libvDSP.dylib (516) <DFEDB210-49D1-3803-88A2-C61DB6A45C3D>  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLi b.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff8b399000 -     0x7fff8b47dfff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (52.30.1) <093A3CCE-953A-365F-9412-775DE0AF2870> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8b62e000 -     0x7fff8b634fff    com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (5.0.9 - 5.0.9) <BB2D573F-0A01-379F-  A2BA-3C454EDCB111>    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRec   ognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff8b7b1000 -     0x7fff8b850e27  com.apple.AppleJPEG (1.0 - 1) <6627DDD9-A8FE-3968-B23A-B6A29AA3919A>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/Versions/A/AppleJPEG
    0x7fff8b851000 -     0x7fff8b856ff7  libmacho.dylib (862) <126CA2ED-DE91-308F-8881-B9DAEC3C63B6> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff8b98e000 -     0x7fff8ba12fff  com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis (1.0 - 1) <BAE4C265-C0B9-3302-AC88-EB5F312FD33C>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/ PerformanceAnalysis
    0x7fff8ba33000 -     0x7fff8ba7dfff  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 -    523) <C7F6A39C-EBC0-3AA7-B355-2DBF988B5A6D>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Framewo  rks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff8c3c4000 -     0x7fff8c5a9ff7  libicucore.A.dylib (531.48) <3CD34752-B1F9-31D2-865D-B5B0F0BE3111> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8c8e0000 -     0x7fff8cdf5ffb  com.apple.JavaScriptCore (10600 - 10600.7.12) <AB93CD01-8F15-3727-9507-E0ED34A1D3B5> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
0x7fff8ce38000 -     0x7fff8ce73fff  com.apple.Symbolication (1.4 - 56045) <D64571B1-4483-3FE2-BD67-A91360F79727> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication
    0x7fff8ce74000 -     0x7fff8cebaff7  libauto.dylib (186) <A260789B-D4D8-316A-9490-254767B8A5F1> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8cecb000 -     0x7fff8cee7fff  com.apple.GenerationalStorage (2.0 - 209.11) <9FF8DD11-25FB-3047-A5BF-9415339B3EEC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/Versions/A/GenerationalStorage
    0x7fff8cef3000 -     0x7fff8cefefff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60061.30.1) <E789748D-F9A7-3CFF-B317-90DF348B1E95> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8cf65000 -     0x7fff8d26aff3  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 758.7) <083019EB-7F58-36F1-BF7F-9E746F692E5C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
```

Comment: Click Show Details and add as much of the log as you can to your question.

Comment: @grgarside okay

Comment: Spigot/Application Manager is malware and also runs the SearchMe toolbar that shows up in your browser extensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash report suggests Spigot software is the problem.

## Removing Spigot

The Safe Mac provide instructions for removing this software, [Adware Removal Guide : Spigot](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-spigot/):

> Spigot is an adware company responsible for a number of different adware programs. At one time, CNET’s Download.com site was wrapping a lot of Mac software in a CNET Installer that also installs Spigot’s adware.

The Safe Mac recommends removing the following files and folders:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.spigot.SearchProtection.plist
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.spigot.ApplicationManager.plist
~/Library/Application Support/Spigot/
```

Spigot themselves provide these steps, [Uninstall Spigot Mac Extensions](http://www.spigot.com/about/contact-us/uninstall-spigot-mac-extensions/).

### Causing the Crash: Spigot

The crash log suggests your Mac has [Spigot](http://www.spigot.com) software installed. The following line provides the clue:

```
Path: /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/Spigot/ApplicationManager
```

It is unlikely you directly installed Spigot software – or want it on your Mac. The Spigot explains more about its role:

> Spigot’s industry leading browser add-ons provide software developers with the ability to maximize monetization per user.

Comment: I downloaded a spigot thing for minecraft, as a replacement to bukkit, is this the same spigot as the one you're talking about? @Graham Miln

Comment: It sounds like an unfortunate name overlap. The Spigot in my answer is unlikely – I hope! – to be the same as the Minecraft related https://www.spigotmc.org project.

Comment: This crap comes with utorrent for one.

Comment: @Jacob_ Once you follow the remove options - especially deleting everything in the `~/Library/Application\ Suport/Spigot` folder (make a Time Machine backup of the Mac if you aren't used to deleting things from the hidden user library folder!) - ask a follow on question if Minecraft doesn't run. It's unlikely it's needed, but making several small questions is best for the site!